# Scroll UITableView only when content doesn't fit

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can I tell a UITableView to scroll ONLY when its content doesn't fit?

I want to avoid the bouncing scroll when all rows fit into the table view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable scrolling in UITableView table when the content fits on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410845/how-to-disable-scrolling-in-uitableview-table-when-the-content-fits-on-the-scree)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView.
UIScrollView has a property alwaysBounceVertical
So try this:

```
    MyTableView.scrollEnabled =  Table_rowcount * rowheight > tableview.frame.size.height;
```

Also look at the alwaysBounceVertical property of UIScrollView.

Comment: I have same question as `Enrico Detoma` Can you provide more information on how to get `Table_rowcount` value? Also Where should I put the above line which you have mentioned in your answer?

Comment: UITableView has a dataSource - wherever you get the data for the table.  This is often an array, so just count the items in that array    Table_rowcode int = [MyArray count];    You can set the scrolling and bouncing properties right after you know how long the array is.

Comment: actually, alwaysBounceVertical = NO is enough to do the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

UITableView sets its `alwaysBounceVertical` property (which defaults to NO on UIScrollView) to YES by default.  You can change this behavior by setting this property to NO.