# How to disable scrolling in UITableView table when the content fits on the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, scroll

I have a few (grouped style) tables in my iphone app (only on part of the screen and added with `Interface Builder` though, not subclassed from `UITableViewController`) that 80% of the time are small and will fit on the screen.  When the table fits on the screen, I'd like to disable scrolling, to make it a bit cleaner.  But if the table goes off the screen (when rows are later added to it), I'd like to enable scrolling again (because otherwise you can't see that content.)

Is there a way to do this?  I can't seem to figure it out.  I do know to do:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

but I'm not sure where, or if I have to calculate the table object size or something to get this to work.

---

**Update**:
Here's the solution that finally worked for me:

```
if (table.contentSize.height < table.frame.size.height) {
   table.scrollEnabled = NO;
 }
else {
   table.scrollEnabled = YES;
 }
```

I run this code after calling `reloadData` on the table, and it calculates the right sizes and appears to work.

`table.frame.size.height` is the actual size of the object (you can see this in `Interface Builder`) displayed on the screen, whereas `table.contentSize.height` is the heights of: the header, the footer, and the height of every cell added together.

Comment: Thanks. That solution worked for me. However, I ended up extending UITableView and overriding reloadData to disable scrollEnabled. The reason is that the table view is loaded when my view controller is created. That way you don't have to call reloadData twice.

Comment: @JoeBlow I think you missed OP's point. The question isn't how to disable bounce, it's how to only enable scrolling (and bounce, most likely) when the tableview needs to scroll.

Comment: Maybe is better to use bounds, because I think if you rotate a bit your table, frame.height is going to change.

Comment: There should be: if (table.contentSize.height <= table.frame.size.height)

Answer (score 435):

I think you want to set

```
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
```

Comment: This works better than contentSize < frame when you are using AutoLayout. Should be accepted answer.

Comment: I'm using auto layout and this answer is exactly what I need.

Comment: better than disabling scrolling

Comment: works like a charm, you can also disable it from the `interface builder` by unticking bounce and bounce horizontally/vertically.

Comment: for Swift - **tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false**

Comment: There is a checkbox in attribute inspector. You can uncheck instead of writing code

Comment: @Feng this checkbox doesn't seem to be working properly (or at all), I had to set it in code to make it work

Comment: Dude this solved one of the nastiest bugs we had in our app. What the heck did apple think when giving this property it's name !?!?

Comment: It works, but... The funny thing is that the Apple documentation says - "The default value is false." 

Comment: @flowGen `UIScrollView` defaults it to false but `UITableView` defaults it to true.

Answer (score 70):

In Swift:

```
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
```

Comment: I always upvote such a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶s̶  "rewrites" because converting to modern syntax requires time.

Answer (score 46):

You can verify the number of visible cells using this function:

```
- (NSArray *)visibleCells
```

This method will return an array with the cells that are visible, so you can count the number of objects in this array and compare with the number of objects in your table.. if it's equal.. you can disable the scrolling using:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

As @Ginny mentioned.. we would can have problems with partially visible cells, so this solution works better in this case:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = (tableView.contentSize.height <= CGRectGetHeight(tableView.frame));
```

In case you are using autoLayout this solution do the job:

```
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO.
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is mostly working for me now.  Only problem I'm having now is when cells are partially visible they still count as visible and thus scrolling gets disabled when in that case I want it to be enabled.

Comment: Figured it out!  Turns out you can't really use visibleCells at all, because of the partially visible cell problem, but this works: `if (table.contentSize.height < table.frame.size.height)` >> see edit in the original post.

Answer (score 30):

So there's are multiple answers and requires a all content at once place so I'm adding this answer:

**If you're using AutoLayout, by setting this only should work for you:**

- In code:

`tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false`

- or In Interface Builder:

Just find this option and `untick` "`Bounce Vertically`" option.

Here's the reference:

[image]

**If you're not using AutoLayout:**

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // Enable scrolling based on content height
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = tableView.contentSize.height > tableView.frame.size.height
 }
```

Answer (score 14):

try this

```
[yourTableView setBounces:NO];
```

Comment: @kyle -- thanks for the note! -- but look that's what happens automatically.  If it is shorter than the screen (or other holder), it does NOT scroll (and obviously won't bounce, coz it won't even scroll).  If it is longer than the screen, it will then scroll (and indeed bounce). No??

Comment: Maybe I've been using collection views too much ... maybe it works as I describe for collection views, but not for UITableView??

Answer (score 10):

You can set enable/disable bounce or scrolling the tableview by selecting/deselecting these in the Scroll View area

[image: Scroll View editing area]

Answer (score 6):

`// Enable scrolling based on content height
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = table.contentSize.height > table.frame.size.height;`

Comment: I think I was enlightened after reading your solution. Many thanks

Comment: I used this in my viewDidAppear

Comment: I meant viewDidLayoutSubviews not viewDidAppear

Answer (score 3):

You can edit this in your storyboard (if you are using one). Under the table view there is a checkbox that says "Scrolling Enabled". Uncheck it and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The default height is 44.0f for a tableview cell I believe. You must be having your datasource in hand in a Array? Then just check if `[array count]*44.0f` goes beyond the frame bounds and if so set `tableview.scrollEnabled = NO`, else set it to YES. Do it where you figure the datasource out for that particular tableview.

Comment: My table cells are different sizes (and may change size at any time; I'm using the heightForRowAtIndexPath method) so I probably wouldn't want to hardcode 44.0f.  I believe that number is the same as tableView.rowHeight anyway?

Comment: You would then be doing your total height calculation in that method. Simple right? If that exceeds screen bound, enable scroll, else leave it disabled.The method would be called for all the visible cells. If you don't have enough data to exceed screen, you can calculate the total height right in that method. Keep adding to a global variable the height it returns on each call and you have your total height.

Comment: Roberto's answer is an easier way of achieving all this and leaving the calculation to the tableview.

Answer (score -3):

This is what worked for me.

```
tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```