# How to lock a UITable from scrolling beyond the items in the table

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that scrolls up too far, to the point where the list of items in the `UITableView` scroll up and then a large amount of whitespace follows it.

How can I stop `UITableView` from scrolling that extra space?

Hope I described it well enough.

Comment: is the contentSize proper?

Comment: are you returning the proper number in numberOfRowsForIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix your problem

```
TableView.bounces=NO;
```

This will remove empty cells

```
TableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this may work for you. Run this code after calling `reloadData` on the table :

```
if (table.contentSize.height < table.frame.size.height) 
{
   table.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
else 
{
   table.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Here ,`table.frame.size.height` is the actual size of the object (you can see this in Interface Builder) displayed on the screen, whereas `table.contentSize.height` is the height of `the header`, `the footer`, and the `height of every cell` added together.

I found it here : [How to disable scrolling in UITableView table when the content fits on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410845/how-to-disable-scrolling-in-uitableview-table-when-the-content-fits-on-the-scree)

Hope you can get something from the answers given their also.