# TableView yOffset changed after reloadData

Tags: ios, tableview

when i custom the `tableHeaderView`, after i `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear`, the tableView `contentOffset.y` will be changed.

Please help me..

---

I have log the tableView contentOffset when i will invoke `reloadData`,
this is the log:

`2016-03-01 10:51:04:362 ~~[1474:387143] will-TableViewContentOffset: {0, -18}
2016-03-01 10:51:04:363 ~~[1474:387143] did-TableViewContentOffset: {0, -62}`

this is how i invoked:

```
    NHDLog(@"will-TableViewContentOffset: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.tableView.

    [self _reloadTableView];

    NHDLog(@"did-TableViewContentOffset: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.tableView.contentOffset));
```

In `viewDidLoad` i have set:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: What's the actuall question?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Is the UITableView or UITableViewController loaded inside any UINavigationController or UITabBarController?

Comment: Post some code, show us what you have tried and explain clearly what is our problem. We will be glad to help you.

Comment: Refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868661/how-to-stop-uitableview-from-returning-to-top-cell-after-popover/34868986#34868986

Comment: @iOSEnthusiatic i have solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This fixed the same problem for me ([thanks to rshinich](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86703)):

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0;
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0;
self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

In Swift:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

In Objective-C

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by removing the following code:

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0):

The `unsuitable estimatedRowHeight` will make the error y. I change the value to fix my issue, I think you should try too.